# Traveling from Germany to England via France by car -> quarantine?

Tags: transit, germany, france, automobiles, england

I have a ferry ticket to England on August 14, I’m German and fully vaccinated. As of August 2, I could travel to England and not having to quarantine. But since I’m driving through France, I’m not sure if I still have to quarantine once I’m in England. I haven’t found anything on the web, and calling the Auswärtige Amt in Germany gave me two different answers, both of them not helpful.

Answer (score 14):

[The latest situation, as announced in the evening of 4 August](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/red-amber-and-green-list-rules-for-entering-england) is that from 4am on Sunday 8 August people fully vaccinated in the UK, Europe or the US arriving from either France or Germany don't have to quarantine.

Anyone arriving in England before 4am on Sunday 8 August who has driven through France has to quarantine.

[The UK government website](https://www.gov.uk/government/news/fully-vaccinated-arrivals-from-france-to-england-must-continue-to-quarantine) says "This includes any fully vaccinated individual who transits through France from either a green or another amber country to reach England."

(There is an exemption for the Eurostar from Belgium which travels through France without stopping, but it's not relevant in your case.)

Comment: Amazingly, my original answer was outdated within hours as the government announced a change to the rules - see update in first paragraph.

Comment: Thank you so much!! I can’t find this information on the official websites though, can you post a link where you found this?    EDIT
 I found the info on the website. This really helped so much!

Comment: Makes you wonder how people arriving at 3am on 8 Aug are so dangerous they have to quarantine, but arriving an hour later on 8 Aug makes you safe. :/

Comment: @FreeMan the entire quarantine system is basically a sham (except for Australia, New Zealand, China, which have hotel quarantine for all). Its all security theater and thus not supposed to make any sense whatsoever.

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one who thinks so, @JonathanReez. Makes me wonder how long it will take before everyone else starts to realize that. `</OT conversational rant>`